# Why can't I set a form's DialogResult inside an event handler in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell, powershell-5.0

Consider this code:

```
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$YesButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$YesButton.Text = "Yes"

$YesButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point( `
    (($Form.Width / 2) - ($YesButton.Width)), 25)

$YesButton.Add_Click({$Form.DialogResult=[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK})

$NoButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$NoButton.Text = "No"

$NoButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point( `
    ($YesButton.Location.X + $YesButton.Width + 10), $YesButton.Location.Y)

$NoButton.Add_Click({$Form.DialogResult=[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel})

$Form.Controls.Add($YesButton)
$Form.Controls.Add($NoButton)

$Timer = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Timer

$Timer.Add_Tick(
{
    $Form.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::None
    $Form.Close() 
})

$Timer.Interval = 3000
$Timer.start()

$Result = $Form.ShowDialog()

if ($Result -eq "OK")
{
    Write-Output "User selected 'Yes'."
}
elseif ($Result -eq "Cancel")
{
    Write-Output "User selected 'No'."
}
elseif ($Result -eq "None")
{
    Write-Output "User selected nothing; prompt timed out."
}
```

If I run it and let the timer tick close the form, I would *expect* it to hit the `elseif ($Result -eq "None")` and thus print `User selected nothing; prompt timed out.`, but instead it's hitting the `elseif ($Result -eq "Cancel")` and printing `User selected 'No'.`

Why does it do that, and how do I get it to return the dialog result that I want?

Comment: Sorry I left the old messages in place when translating to an [mcve].  I've updated. It's hitting the second branch `$Result -eq "Cancel"` and I'm wondering why it's not hitting the third `$Result -eq "None"`.  See my updates.

Comment: It's hitting the second branch -- `elseif ($Result -eq "Cancel")`.  It's not even evaluating the third branch, so it doesn't matter what I put in there.

Comment: That's only if the no button is clicked, which it's not, right?  I'm not clicking either button -- yes or no.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the timer closes the form, DialogResult is changed to None, BUT then $Form.close() is called immediately after.

Since the Close() method changes DialogResult to Cancel, switching the Close() method with where you manually change DialogResult and change that new enumerated value to Abort will get the conditionals working as intended.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Why do I have to use "Abort" -- why doesn't "None" work (I've tested and confirmed that's true, I just don't know why)?

Comment: None is the value of DialogResult when the window is just open and not closed. It essentially says, "The window is currently open and there is no change in state." You don't really have to use Abort; you could use Ignore or No as well. You've just got to make sure you set it to a value you know will never be set elsewhere in the script

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all that you want, I would keep it simple and consider to use the old fashion [`WScript.Shell Popup`](https://ss64.com/vb/popup.html):

```
$Result = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).Popup("Do you like to continue?", 3, "Title", (1 + 32 + 4096))
```